# Mixing CommonJS and Order Loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, intern

I need to supply my code in plain JS so I'm using the `intern/order!path/to/file` syntax in my unit test.  However, I also need to provide a `fetch` Polyfill for Node.  How do I mix both `order` and `commonjs` modules?

Comment: Tag your question with javascript and nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `intern/dojo/node!<cjs module>` instead of `intern/order!<cjs module>`.

The `order` plugin is only required when modules have to be loaded in a certain order. This is necessary because the AMD loader used by Intern loads modules asynchronously. It starts the loading process in the order specified in the dependencies list, but modules may not finish loading in that order. The order plugin ensures that a module is fully loaded before the next module's loading process begins.

The node loader is synchronous, so modules will be loaded in the order given in the dependencies list.